# How can I improve my database for storing images?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I'm thinking how to store images into my database. I have 2 "macro-entities", users and animals.

**USERS**

```
idUsers bigint(20) AI PK 
name varchar(255) 
surname varchar(255) 
birthdate date 
email varchar(250) 
psw varchar(128) 
tk int(11) 
created_time datetime
mod_time datetime  
idCategory tinyint(4) FK
idCountry tinyint(4) FK
idGender tinyint(4) FK
description text
```

**ANIMALS**

```
idAnimals bigint(20) AI PK 
name varchar(255) 
idGender tinyint(4) FK
idUsers bigint(20) FK
birthdate date 
visits int(11) 
identification varchar(200) 
idBreed smallint(6) FK
created_time datetime
mod_time datetime 
description text
```

**IMG**

```
idImg bigint(20) PK 
filename text 
created_time datetime 
mime_type varchar(50)
```

The easiest solution is create a cross table users_img and another cross table animal_img, but It does not seem very elegant. Like so:

**IMG_USERS**

```
idImg bigint(20) PK FK
idUsers bigint(20) PK FK
```

**IMG_ANIMALS**

```
idImg bigint(20) PK FK
idAnimals bigint(20) PK FK
```

It would work well, but if I want to give the possibility to create albums in the future, I can't do it.

For albums it's simple:

**ALBUMS**

```
idAlbums bigint(20) AI PK 
name varchar(255) 
descriptions text 
created_time datetime 
modified_time datetime 
slug varchar(255)
```

**IMG_ALBUMS**

```
idImg bigint(20) PK FK
idAlbum bigint(20) PK FK
```

**ENGINE** InnoDB

I should create 2 another cross table "ALBUMS_USERS" and "ALBUMS_ANIMALS"...It is not maintainable! I can't create a simple, good and elegant database for 2 or more "macro-entities". How can do it? What's the best way?

The queries will be like:

- without albums: "select all images where idUsers/idAnimals = X". When I visits the user's (or his animal) page, in a section I would like to see the thumbnails of his images.
- with albums: "select all albums where idUsers/idAnimals = X". When I visits the user's page, I would like to see the thumbnails of his albums.

I'll use amazon s3 for storing images and albums. the routes of images are:

**1 - Without albums**

my-bucket-app/[user|animal]-[idUsers|animals]/img/[filename]-[width-of-image].[extension]

ex: my-bucket-app/user-1/img/1_102020304-400.jpg (400 is the lenght of long side of the image)

**2 - With albums**

my-bucket-app/[user|animals]-[idUsers|animals]/album-[idAlbum]/[filename]-[width-of-image].[extension]

ex: my-bucket-app/user-1/albums-1/1_102020304-400.jpg (400 is the lenght of long side of the image)

the filenames are generated by this function in php:

```
$userID . _ . md5(microtime());
```

I'll store into a bucket, 4 images of every upladed images. ex:

1_102020304-**400**.jpg for the thumbnails

1_102020304-**2048**.jpg for the large-images size

1_102020304-**1024**.jpg for the medium-images size

1_102020304-**original**.jpg for the original images

Precisely why I thought to store only this part of image's name **1_102020304**-400.jpg into "filename" field and adding size and mimetype (this is memorized into another field "mime_type") with a function.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FearOfAddingTables

Comment: hi, interesting reading. I just add more information about queries. What are your advice? thanks so much

Comment: An image is an image.  There is no reason to store it differently depending on whether it is in an album (or multiple albums) or not.  Use the database to organize albums, not the directory system.  The details of the image filenames is also unnecessary unless you want to make size, etc, obvious to the user.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
So, one table "img" for images, one table "albums" for albums. Another table many-to-many "img_albums" to relate them, but I don't understand how to relate them to users and animals. I must create another tables "albums_animals" and "albums_users"?

Comment: Why do you think that "ALBUMS_USERS" and "ALBUMS_ANIMALS" are necessary? If there are "IMG_USERS" and "IMG_ANIMALS" available and the mapping between IMGs and Albums is known (via IMG_ALBUMS), you can determine which User/Animal is in which Album on the fly via SELECT statements (assuming that your forreign key relationships are consistent).

Answer (score 1):

```
idGender tinyint(4) FK
idCountry tinyint(4) FK
```

Don't normalize trivial things; use `CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET ascii` for `gender`.  There are standard 2-letter country codes.

```
name varchar(255)
```

Don't get carried away with VARCHAR lengths.

You have not mentioned the ENGINE -- use InnoDB.

```
idUsers bigint(20)
```

You are expecting more than 4 billion (the limit of `INT UNSIGNED`)?  INT is 4 bytes; BIGINT is 8.  Smaller is better.

In your many-to-many mappings (which *are* necessary), you are likely to need an index going the opposite direction.

```
mime_type varchar(50)
```

A simple ENUM should suffice.

You can't finalize a schema without specifying what the queries will be like.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I just add more information about engine and queries in the first post.